# Postsharp installer bug: .Net 2.0 not presented

Tags: postsharp

There is an issue with PostSharp 1.5 and 2.0 that won't let you install it on the Windows 7 machine with the error message ".NET Framework 2.0 is not present on this computer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work around the issue you have to run the installer while being logged in with Administrator account. Not Admin group and not "run as Administrator", you have to be logged in with the Administrator account. Hope that helps, if someone has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also open a command prompt under Administrator priviledge, then invoke the .msi installer

Comment: I can see that this was your first answer to a question, so you didn't have the rep to post this as a comment, but in the future, you might want to consider posting this as a comment. Answers are supposed to be a solution to the problem that you are pretty confident will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. May I humbly suggest that you might also want to stick to the matter at hand when commenting on an answer to a question.

Comment: I came across this through the moderation queue - not via trying to answer, this answer is a little light, and would have probably been a good comment. Don't take offense, I am just trying to make this a better site mate and help you get a load of rep while at the same time helping the folks who are asking questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason was incorrect registry value -
see http://www.sharpcrafters.com/forum/Topic8623-18-1.aspx#m8766

> the registry value "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET
>   Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\SP" is set to 0 on your computer but was
>   expected to be 1.
>
> you can set this registry value to 1 for the time of installation,
>   then set it back to 0

it is a known , not PostSharp specific issue: https://superuser.com/questions/106647/net-framework-3-5-sp1-on-wind...